# Extending a QCompleter to show additional information

Tags: python, qt, qcompleter

I have a QCompleter using my own QAbstractItemModel to help autocomplete a QLineEdit. It works  great. I was wondering how I might go to add additional data displayed in the QCompleter's list of suggestions. For example, the kind of stuff shown in NetBeans when you press Ctrl+space:

[image]

Is there a way to subclass QCompleter to get it to show additional data?

Comment: You can use `QCompleter::setPopup` to set custom popup view. You can try to use `QTableView`, or subclass `QListView` and implement additional data displaying manually, or create your own view class.