# Qt4: How to implement a QCompleter with side-note?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I want to implement a completer like this:

```
----------------------
|1001                |
----------------------
|1001001  |  "Coffee"|
|1001002  |  "Sugar" |
----------------------
```

So, the "1001" is some id a user will input. I want the completer to complete the id for the user. I can easily use `QCompleter` to complete the id. However since there are so many ids, I want the completer to show side-note(like the "Coffee") for the users so they don't need to remember a lot of ids.

So I want to know can I implement such a completer with Qt4(PyQt4 particularly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question here: [Extending a QCompleter to show additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958472/extending-a-qcompleter-to-show-additional-information).

`QCompleter::setPopup` is the way to go, allows you to provide a custom widget for showing completion hints.